# connecting fire Store to the music app using flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have created a music app using flutter I want to store user favorites and recently played songs in Firebase fire store so provide the code to store the data in fire store an I am getting error:

> ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(java.lang.Exception: Failed to load FirebaseOptions from resource. Check that you have defined values.xml correctly., Exception, Cause: null, Stacktrace: java.lang.Exception: Failed to load FirebaseOptions from resource. Check that you have defined values.xml correctly.

Comment: It seems like you didn't complete the setup steps that are documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android

Answer (score 0):

Include additional options when initializing the app. You can find the necessary keys in the Firebase console under project settings.

```
Future<void> main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: FirebaseOptions(
          apiKey: 'your_api_key',
          appId: 'your_app_id',
          messagingSenderId: 'your_messaging_sender_id',
          projectId: 'your_project_id',
          storageBucket: 'your_storage_bucket',
        )
      );
runApp(MyApp());
}
```